# How I can get Sold Item from Square connect?

Tags: square-connect

I am trying to develop application which fetch data from square. I need to    retrieve sales items how it can be retrieve from API.

I have read documentation and from that I am able to know that I need to get payments and from payments I can get sold item.

I have used that and I am getting out put. I am attaching JSON file what I am getting.

Issue is that item price which I have marked as sales is 10 but I am getting 1000 in response.

Following is my `GET` request:

https://connect.squareup.com/v1/99TNZKRBWEAJV/payments/

`Token` : c94wMrolAsZC8k3LlQ47mg

Why I am getting price 1000 instead of 10? Quick help needed.

Comment: OAuth access tokens are sensitive information and should be kept private. If this was your personal access token, you can go to the developer portal at https://connect.squareup.com/ to refresh it.

Comment: Thanks for reply I will refresh this thing.And Its my testing account no confidential data with account.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#workingwithmonetaryamounts):

> The `amount` field [of the `Money` object] is always in the **smallest denomination** of the
>   currency indicated by `currency_code`.

For US dollars, monetary amounts returned by the Connect API are in cents. Therefore, an item with a price of $10.00 has a corresponding monetary `amount` in the API of `1000`.